# My laptop is super slow. What could be a possible reason?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, lenovo-laptop

Previously I was a desktop user and everything on my Intel [Core i5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i5)-[4440](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors#%22Haswell-DT%22_(quad-core,_22_nm)) worked very well. For the last few days I start using the laptop. Now I see it's running super slow.

Please someone check the screenshot and let me know what could be reason. For example, my disk is 100% most of the time. I am not sure how 200 KB/sec read and 200 KB/sec write make the disk usage to 100%.

My CPU never goes to 100% something, and it's quite responsive. Starting two days ago, the update takes a whole day.

[image]

This is a brand new machine, Lenovo IdeaPad 310 (15") 4 GB RAM 1 TB. How do I make it work faster?

Comment: It looks like there's a process that's doing a lot of writing, but the list you posted was incomplete and sorted by read access, not write access, so we're likely not seeing the culprit in this image.  I would install Process Monitor from Sysinternals (now a Microsoft property) and that should provide a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: VS2015 has perf issues, the diag tools create reports and hogs your slow HDD. replace the HDD with a SSD and your device will be faster

Comment: @magicandre1981 just put 8gb more and disk is now come to 3-30%. look fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1 - Buy A Solid State Drive (SSD)

Seriously, conventional hard disk drives are real bottlenecks nowadays, as you are experiencing now.

## Option 2 - Disable Disk Eaters

Look at what processes are using the most disk bandwidth and research how to disable them (assuming you don't need them.)

From your screenshot, it looks like a lot of Visual Studio processes are using a fair bit of I/O, so you should look into making Visual Studio leaner.